# Change colour of L.circleMarker()

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

It's probably a simple solution, but I'd like to change the colour of my L.circleMarkers from blue to green. Based on the [documentation](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/api/v2.2.0/l-circlemarker/), it says you can pass it an options object to change things such as colour. What I tried is this:

```
return L.circleMarker(ll, {radius: number}, '#006600');
```

Passing it the hex colour code for green. I also tried to create an actual object like this:

```
var optionsObject = {color: "#006600"};
```

None of the methods I tried work. I'm relatively new to JavaScript and MapBox, and I would appreciate it if someone could help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can just do something like:

```
return L.circleMarker(ll, {radius: number, color: '#006600'});
```

Answer (score 0):

For change color circleMarker use `NameCircle.setStyle({color: 'color name'});`

Like this https://jsfiddle.net/magi2109/xd3Lmoqb/

[image: circleMarker]

my describtion link is [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/380460/155152).